# How do I read a file line by line in C from the terminal?

Tags: c, terminal, scanf, fopen

I have read that I can use fopen to read a file line by line, but I want to access the file from the terminal as such.
This is what I have tried:

`$ ./myprogram < input.txt > output.txt`

I'm not sure if there's a way to do it with scanf or another way?

Comment: Read `input.txt' line by line and use `fprintf` write to `output.txt'.

Comment: This question has been asked in far less broad "write my code for me" ways [many, many, times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+file+line+by+line+%5BC%5D). I suggest reading some of them for inspiration.

Comment: Short answer is `#define BUFSZ 1024 ... char buf[BUFSZ] = ""; while (fgets (buf, BUFSZ, stdin)) fputs (buf, stdout);`

Answer (score 1):

Here, if you think about what you are doing, you are simply reading continually from `stdin` and writing the same bytes to `stdout` until you receive an `EOF`. While you can use a character oriented approach (e.g. `getchar`), a read with a fixed length buffer will dramatically cut down the number of reads and writes you have.

Simply declare a buffer of comfortable size, `1024` (or use the default `BUFSIZ` provided, generally `8192` on Linux and `512` on windoze). Then repeatedly call `fgets` reading a buffers worth of characters at a time and writing them back to `stdout` with `fputs`. That's about as simple as it gets.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSZ 1024

int main (void) {

    char buf[BUFSZ] = "";

    while (fgets (buf, BUFSZ, stdin))
        fputs (buf, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Ideally, you would want a buffer size just longer than the longest line, although it really doesn't matter what size it is. You can read each line all at once, or in multiple calls to `fgets`. The only difference is the number of function calls made.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define BUFSIZE 1024

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
    {
        char *line = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE);
        if (!line)
        {
            printf("malloc buffer failed...\n");
            return 1;
        }
        memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
        FILE *fp;
        FILE *writefp;
        int c;
        int count = 0;
        int count_buf = BUFSIZE;
        char scanf_answer;

        if (argc != 3)
        {
            printf("./myprogram <input.txt> output.txt\n");
            return 1;
        }
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        for (;;)
        {
            c = getc(fp);
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                printf("%s\n", line);
                printf("<Did you want to write this line to [%s]?>", argv[2]);
                scanf("%c", &scanf_answer);
                if (scanf_answer == 'Y' || scanf_answer == 'y')
                {
                    writefp = fopen(argv[2], "a+");
                    fprintf(writefp, "%s\n", line);
                    fclose(writefp);
                }
                memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
            }
            else if (c == EOF)
            {
                printf("%s\n", line);
                printf("<Did you want to write this line to [%s]?>", argv[2]);
                scanf("%c", &scanf_answer);
                if (scanf_answer == 'Y' || scanf_answer == 'y')
                {
                    writefp = fopen(argv[2], "a+");
                    fprintf(writefp, "%s\n", line);
                    fclose(writefp);
                }
                printf("End of file\n");
                break;
            }
            if (count >= count_buf)
            {
                line = realloc(line, BUFSIZE);
                count_buf += BUFSIZE;
                if (!line)
                {
                   printf("realloc buffer failed...\s");
                   return 1;
                }
                count = 0;
            }
            sprintf(line,"%c%c", line, c);
            ++count;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
```

This code will print each line, you decide each line to write to the output.txt, and in the file end, it will print `End of file`

Comment: You need to review this code.  Your sprints attempts to overwrite `line[0]` with each character.  However, `c` isn’t defined, but you treat it as an `int` (correct) or `char` (incorrect); it isn’t a string so `%s` is the wrong format.

Comment: If you fix those mechanics, you’ve not taken any steps to process lines, nor to prevent overflow of your `line` buffer.  Files are often megabytes if not gigabytes in size, or larger.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry for my code, I just wrote some snippets of code to remind the author of the problem, forget some basic grammar definitions, thanks for you your reminder

Comment: Much better — but…  Remember that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, so you need `int c;`.  You also still can't use `sprintf(line, "%s", c)` because `c` is not a pointer to a null terminated string.  You could use `%c`.  You then need to ensure you write to a new position each time — you're still overwriting `line[0]` on each iteration.  Also, you copy the newline to the start of each line — or would if the `sprintf()` was working properly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I changed the code, thank you for your teaching

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, I set a count to make sure the line variable will not overflow and then change the sprintf to make sure I do not overwrite line, I learned a lot with you

Answer (score 0):

> `$ ./myprogram < input.txt > output.txt`

The command you posted uses a shell feature called IO redirection to produce input on stdin from one file and redirect output to stdout to the other file.

To take lines as input to your program is super easy even for lines of arbitrary length if you can use POSIX `getline()`. Please consult the manpage (linked below) for details.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // this is the buffer data is read to (including trailing newline)
    char *buffer = 0;
    // this will be set to the size of the buffer
    size_t buffer_size = 0;
    // this will be set to the number of bytes read
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    while ((bytes_read = getline(&buffer, &buffer_size, stdin)) != -1) {
        // do something with line
        printf("%s", buffer);
        // the same buffer will be reused in the next loop iteration
    }
    // free buffer eventually
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out < test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
[...]
```

Note that `scanf()` is for taking *formatted input*, which reading lines is not. I suggest you get to learn more about the different approaches to IO (on streams) here:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-on-Streams.html#I_002fO-on-Streams

For reference:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html